# Android Studio change button background color with custom drawable

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I have a custom drawable using <shape> in xml, with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/blue"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="150dp"/>
</shape>
```

on a button, and I would like to programmatically change the button's color to another color while keeping the shape it gets from the custom drawable. Is this possible?

Comment: use appCompat button in your xml. It is more editable. You can edit background tint of button object in class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont want to use the normal backgrounTint in your xml folder :

```
    android:backgroundTint="yourcolor"
```

Use this Code in your java code :

```
    yourbutton.setBackgroundTintList(this.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorname));
```